# delete multiple files from the folder

Tags: php

how can i delete multiple files from the folder?

```
code:$query=$this->main_model->get($id);

if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            unlink("uploads/".$id."/".$row->img_name);
            unlink("uploads/".$id."/".$row->img_name_tn);
            unlink("uploads/".$id."/".$row->file);
            unlink("uploads/".$id."/".$row->file2);
            unlink("uploads/".$id."/Thumbs.db");
        }
            rmdir("uploads/".$id);
}
```

here is the code i used but it delete the files at ones. and how can i delete all files from the folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

originally from php.net:

```
<?php
 $dir = '/uploads/';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // strip the current and previous directory items
            unlink($dir . $file); // you can add some filters here, aswell, to filter datatypes, file, prefixes, suffixes, etc
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: The loop performance is really poor! Especially in network file systems such as NFS. PHP needs a built-in function to delete the entire directory quickly. Maybe an extension can do that.

Answer (score 3):

I found this at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#100092):

```
"The shortest recursive delete possible"

function rrmdir($path) {
   return is_file($path)?
     @unlink($path):
     array_map('rrmdir',glob($path.'/*'))==@rmdir($path)
   ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
function delete_files($dirname) {
   if (is_dir($dirname))
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
            unlink($dirname."/".$file);   
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a recursive function. A comment from the [rmdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) page have written a function on how to do it, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#98622. This code will delete the folder and everything in it.

```
<?php 
 function rrmdir($dir) { 
   if (is_dir($dir)) { 
     $objects = scandir($dir); 
     foreach ($objects as $object) { 
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object); 
       } 
     } 
     reset($objects); 
     rmdir($dir); 
   } 
 } 
?>
```